# How to setup AppDelegate in Xamarin.Mac for NSApplicationDelegate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I have an App that uses Xamarin.Forms with UWP/Andoid/iOS and want to port it to Xamarin.Mac. The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/get-started/hello-mac) suggests to subclass NSApplicationDelegate via:

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : NSApplicationDelegate
```

Unfortunately, Visual Studio doesn't find the `NSApplicationDelegate-class. I tried to specify it via:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS.NSApplicationDelegate
```

Here it does find `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.MacOS` but still no `NSApplicationDelegate`.

It does find `FormsApplicationDelegate` but the solution I found on the web that uses that class creates an extra window that I don't want.

Comment: Are you creating a Xamarin.Forms' based Xamarin.Mac application, a Xamarin.Mac application based upon a storyboard or a Xamarin.Mac application based solely on code?

Comment: A Xamarin Forms based app.

Comment: its in AppKit: AppKit.NSApplicationDelegate

Comment: Your registered AppDelegate has to be subclassed from `FormsApplicationDelegate`, in the `Main` function, NSApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate should be assigned a new instance of AppDelegate and your info.plist needs to NOT contain a "Main storyboard file base name".

Comment: This might be a better guide to follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/mac . The guide you linked is not for Xamarin.Forms, but for working with a pure Xamarin.Mac app (no Xam.Forms)